# How many times a word is used in a given statement. MIPS MARS assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I want the user to input a word and in the given statement hardcoded into the code count how many times the word appears in statement.

#### This is what i have so far in my code:

```
.data
prompt: .asciiz "enter word you are looking: "
string:  .asciiz "hello how are you doing today. thank you for coming. hello . hello.  "
input:   .space 1000
.text

li $v0,4
la $a0, prompt
syscall
li $v0, 8
la $a0, input
li $a1, 500
syscall
lb $t2, input
la $t1, string 
   
if:  
       lb $t3, 0($t1)
       beqz $a1 exit
       beq  $t3, $t2, next
       addi $a1, $a1, -1
       addi $t1, $t1, 1
       j if   
next:
       addi $t0, $t0, 1
       addi $t1, $t1, 1
       addi $a1, $a1, -1
       j if 
      
exit:
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t0
syscall
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

#### Expected result:

If user puts in hello: `hello - 3`

Any help would be great.

Comment: It seems like you only ever check the first letter of the input (kept in `$t2`). Where in your code do you proceed to the second and subsequent letters?

Comment: That is what I am trying to get it to do. I cant figure it out.

Comment: the most straightforward way is to create a loop, which compares letter by letter. If one word is exhausted sooner then other (no more letter available), then they are different (even if all characters up to that point were equal, i.e. "ab" vs "abc" should report difference, but first two character tests will produce "equal"). If the fetched characters are different, the words are different. If you did exhaust characters from both words at the same time, then the words are same (otherwise you would detect different characters before).

Comment: (it may take some skill to organize the checks and code flow in a way to have not too many code paths, duplicating the tests for different cases too much, and yet to have it correct for all kind of inputs (consider also empty words, etc), but if you will toy with it for a while, and not just accept the very first version, you will probably pull it out in few lines of code (although doing the word splitting of original sentence while also comparing with single "needle" string is not completely trivial like comparing two numbers, so some friction is expected even for seasoned programmer)

Comment: @Ped7g thanks for the tips! almost got it!